# In neo4j is there a way to get path between more than 2 random nodes whose direction of relation is not known

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a scenario where I have more than 2 random nodes.

I need to get all possible paths connecting all three nodes. I do not know the direction of relation and the relationship type.

**Example** : I have in the graph database with three nodes `person->Purchase->Product`.

I need to get the path connecting these three nodes. But I do not know the order in which I need to query, for example if I give the query as person-Product-Purchase, it will return no rows as the order is incorrect.

So in this case how should I frame the query?

In a nutshell I need to find the path between more than two nodes where the match clause may be mentioned in what ever order the user knows.

Comment: I don't understand this. Could you please create and share a sample graph using http://console.neo4j.org?

Comment: In the console, default Matrix example, I created a new node Oracle, Trinity ->(knows) Oracle and The Architect ->(Knows) Oracle

**start n=node:node_auto_index(name='Trinity'), m=node:node_auto_index(name='The Architect') 
create (Oracle {name:'Oracle'}), n-[:KNOWS]->Oracle, m-[:KNOWS]->Oracle**

When I query to get the path connecting **Neo, oracle and Cypher**, I should get **Neo -> (Knows) Morpheus ->(Knows) Cypher ->(Knows) Agent Smith ->(Knows) The Architect ->(Knows) Oracle**
and **Neo ->(Loves) Trinity ->(Knows) Oracle <-(Knows) The Architect <-(Knows) Agent Smith <-(Knows) Cypher**

Comment: could you please *share* your dataset using the console? would be much easier.

Comment: Created a dataset and query based on *Wes Freeman*. This query returns 72 rows. [http://console.neo4j.org/?id=gwgp70]. Any better way would help me.

Answer (score 2):

You could list all of the nodes in multiple bound identifiers in the `start`, and then your `match` would find the ones that match, in any order. And you could do this for N items, if needed. For example, here is a query for 3 items:

```
start a=node:node_auto_index('name:(person product purchase)'), 
      b=node:node_auto_index('name:(person product purchase)'), 
      c=node:node_auto_index('name:(person product purchase)') 
match p=a-->b-->c 
return p;
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/tbwu2d

I actually just made a blog post about how `start` works, which might help:
http://wes.skeweredrook.com/cypher-it-all-starts-with-the-start/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really helpful. I have provided the dataset I used here with. The query returns 72 rows (All paths are the same I guess). [http://console.neo4j.org/?id=gwgp70]. But is there a way to get only one shortestpath which is a best match. Also when executing the query sometimes I get an error * Error: org.neo4j.kernel.guard.GuardOperationsCountException: max ops (ops=10001)*. Please advice on this.

Comment: The console has a limit on the number of ops you can run (so it doesn't bring the server to its knees)--it's really meant for small graph examples.

Comment: Ok. But I was getting 72 rows in the output. Am I making any mistake in the query? or is there a better way to rephrase my query?

Comment: The console you linked just has the Neo example... can you try sharing again?

Comment: I think it's that there are actually that many different ways of finding those paths, with your variable length paths.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be acceptable to make several queries ? In your case you'd automatically generate 6 queries with all the possible combinations (factorial on the number of variables)

Comment: I do not want to do that way because, if the number of nodes increases then number of possible combination and so the number of times I query the database increases. This is an overhead. Instead is there a way to achieve my case?

Comment: If you don't know the order, you have to try all the possibilities. You don't really have a choice, I doubt you can find a 'magic' trick. Wes's response above is probably the cleanest way to do it, but it also tests all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to first get three sets of nodes (`s`,`m`,`e`). These sets may be the same as in the question (or contain partially or completely different nodes). The sets are important, because starting, middle and end node are not fixed.

Here is the code for the [Matrix example](http://console.neo4j.org/r/poqbuk) with added nodes.

```
match (s) where s.name in ["Oracle", "Neo", "Cypher"]
match (m) where m.name in ["Oracle", "Neo", "Cypher"] and s <> m 
match (e) where e.name in ["Oracle", "Neo", "Cypher"] and s <> e and m <> e 
match rel=(s)-[r1*1..]-(m)-[r2*1..]-(e)
return s, r1, m, r2, e, rel;
```

The additional `where` clause makes sure the same node is not used twice in one result row.
The relations are matched with one or more edges (`*1..`) or hops between the nodes `s` and `m` or `m` and `e` respectively and disregarding the directions.

Note that cypher 3 syntax is used here.